# How can I close a SuiteScript 2.0 SFTP connection?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am using the N/sftp module in SuiteScript 2.0 and can successfully send files to my SFTP location. I am however having trouble on my SFTP location, since it seems like the connection from NetSuite is never closed. This means that every now and again, the maximum amount of connections on my SFTP server is reached and no further connections are allowed - forcing me to restart my SFTP service(on my own server).

This is my code:

```
var connection = sftp.createConnection({
        username: 'username',
        passwordGuid: '123456789',
        url: 'url.server.com',
        hostKey: ''
    });
    //log.error('CONNECTION',connection);

    var myFileToUpload = file.create({
        name: internalID + '.json',
        fileType: file.Type.JSON,
        contents: postData,
        description: 'SO', 
        encoding: file.Encoding.UTF8
    });


    connection.upload({
    directory: username + '/',
    filename: internalID + '.json',
    file: myFileToUpload,
    replaceExisting: false
   });
```

The SuiteScript documentation does not provide any function to close the connection. Is there a way to close this?

If not, I am thinking of attempting to close connections on my SFTP service that have been open for more than a certain amount of time. I don't feel that this is the best way of dealing with the situation. Any input on this or alternative solutions would also be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was much rejoicing when NS announced SFTP support. I reported the issue you write about last year and apparently it's not been fixed yet.

This, coupled with the N/sftp's inability to list files in remote directories, lead me to abandon N/sftp as a production ready module. It's really easy to spin up an external service to manage sftp connections. I use express and passport with simple bearer tokens for authenticating the inbound connections.

I've also done the transport as scheduled cron/windows scheduler jobs.

I've done this on AWS Lambda, Azure and Heroku.

Key transport is of course an issue. AWS allows you to encrypt your properties at rest. My preference is for that but nothing is as secure as Netsuite's intended usage of keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll look into using your recommendations. I find it disappointing that the N/sftp module seems so incomplete - it's very useful to have this functionality in Netsuite.